# MySQL Join 2 tables and SUM revenue - combine two query into one

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables. I need get sum revenues for last 30 days where is same date and same user_id.

I need to combine these queries into one JOIN SQL query:

```
select * from user_revenue where user_id=$id AND `cdate` >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
select * from user_revenue_publisher where user_id=$id AND `cdate` >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

TABLE: user_revenue

```
USER_ID                CDATE             REVENUE
1                      2019-03-15        15
2                      2019-03-15        18
5                      2019-03-15        29
9                      2019-03-15        11
```

TABLE: user_revenue_publisher

```
USER_ID                CDATE             REVENUE
1                      2019-03-15        15
1                      2019-03-15        50
9                      2019-03-15        21
9                      2019-03-15        18
```

I NEED RESULT:

```
USER_ID                CDATE             REVENUE
1                      2019-03-15        80
2                      2019-03-15        18
5                      2019-03-15        29
9                      2019-03-15        50
```

I want to mention that each user does not have rows in the 2 tables, so some users have no revenue / no rows in table (eg. user 5 has only rows in table user_revenue not in table user_revenue_publisher).

Comment: Why both tags, SQL Server and MySQL?

Comment: Removed the sql server tag as this is clearly mysql and not sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to combine the two resultsets into a single set with the `UNION ALL` set operator, and then use that query as an inline view. The outer query can perform 
a `GROUP BY` operation to collapse rows, and use a `SUM` aggregate function in to add up the revenue.

Something like this:

```
SELECT q.user_id
     , q.cdate
     , SUM(q.revenue) AS revenue
  FROM ( SELECT r.user_id
              , r.cdate
              , r.revenue
           FROM user_revenue r
          WHERE r.user_id  = ?
            AND r.cdate   >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -30 DAY
          UNION ALL
         SELECT p.user_id
              , p.cdate
              , p.revenue
           FROM user_revenue_publisher p
          WHERE p.user_id  = ?
            AND p.cdate   >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -30 DAY
       ) q
 GROUP
    BY q.user_id
     , q.cdate
 ORDER
    BY q.user_id
     , q.cdate
```

---

There are other query patterns that will return results that may also (or better) satisfy the specification with better performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your SQL query works great! I spent many hours on it. Thank you again!